# How to correctly replicate response body of an Octokit requests' response for webmock stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webmock, octokit

Octokit responses are of type [Sawyer::Response](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sawyer/Sawyer/Response)

They look like this:

```
{:name=>"code.py",
:content => "some content"}
```

I am trying to stub my request like so

```
reponse_body = {:content => "some content"}
stub_request(:any, /.*api.github.com\/repos\/my_repo\/(.*)\/code.py/).to_return(:status => 200, :body => response_body)
```

In my code I then call response.content, so I want to be able to get the content from the response.

I currently get the error:  'WebMock::Response::InvalidBody: must be one of: [Proc, IO, Pathname, String, Array]. 'Hash' given'.  What is the proper format for response_body?  If I turn it into a json, I then can't do response.content on the object in my code.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a hash as the expected response and Webmock doesn’t know what that should be encoded to ([see this Webmock issue](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/449)). As you mentioned, you could use `response_body.to_json`, however you would then be unable to use the dot notation to access data.

Since you’re using RSpec, I’d make use of [Test Doubles](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs) to pretend you have a `Sawyer::Resource` object:

```rb
response_body = 
  [
    double("Sawyer::Resource",
      {
        :name=>"code.py",
        :content => "some content"
      })
  ]
```

You should then be able to access data using the dot notation like you would with the actual response.

Comment: Nice idea, I thought so too, but get same error on the double. `WebMock::Response::InvalidBody: must be one of: [Proc, IO, Pathname, String, Array].'RSpec::Mocks::Double' given`

Comment: Gah! I made a typo. The `response_body` should be an array with one element. That element would then be the test double. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thats all very well and will work, but now the code under test we receive an array, when it would normally receive a hash. In fact, the double is not required if the hash is returned within the array, as that is an allowed return type.

Comment: This leads to error if I use response.content in code: NoMethodError: undefined method `content' for [#<Double "Sawyer::Resource">]:Array

Comment: If you're not expecting a response body that's an array you can remove those square brackets.
`response_body = double("Sawyer::Resource", { :name=>"code.py", :content => "some content"})`

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the JSON body as a string, and an appropriate Content-Type header. E.g., to stub the call

```
Octokit::Client.new.user(user_login)
```

you need something like

```
stub_request(:get, "https://api.github.com/users/#{user_login}")
  .to_return(
    status: 200,
    body: user_json, # a string containing the JSON data
    headers: { content_type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
  )
```

(If you don't provide the Content-Type header, Octokit won't try to parse the JSON and you'll just get the raw string back.)

If you look at the [Octokit source](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/841dd32123a83f746f708e486958517a46dfd58e/spec/octokit/client/users_spec.rb#L248-L250) you can see how they use Webmock in their own tests. (The `json_response()` method called in that test is in [`helper.rb`](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/841dd32123a83f746f708e486958517a46dfd58e/spec/helper.rb#L251-L258).)

Comment: The thing I was missing was the response header, thanks!

Comment: I will just add that user_json = "{\"content\": \"some content\"}" for above question.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem, and in the end solved it by stubbing out the Octokit client. In order to check the test coverage within Octokit, I followed instructions [here](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb#running-and-writing-new-tests).

Octokit requests are all tested with [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr), so assuming you are happy with their test coverage, it is reasonably safe to stub Octokit::Client within your application.

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone is still confused, here is a complete sample how Octokit call could be tested with rspec.

**Method:**

```
require 'octokit'

def get_user_name(login)
  Octokit.configure { |c|  c.api_endpoint = 'https://git.my_company.com/api/v3/' }
  client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => 'my_token')
  response = client.user(login)
  return response.name
end
```

**Test:**

```
describe '#get_user_name' do
  it 'should return name' do
    response_body = {:name => "James Bond"}
    stub_request(:get, "https://git.my_company.com/api/v3/users/bondj").
      to_return(status: 200,
                body: JSON.generate(response_body),
                headers: { content_type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' })

    result = subject.send(:get_user_name, 'bondj')
    expect(result).to eq('James Bond')
  end
end
```